# getElementsByTagName within an element javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

Why does the following return 0?

```
 <p id="g">
 <div>kk</div>
 <div>ee</div>
 <div>jff</div>
 </p>


  <script type="text/javascript">
  var ii = document.getElementById("g");
  var hh = ii.getElementsByTagName('div');
  document.write(hh.length);
  </script>
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Because you can't have a `<div>` in a `<p>`. Paragraphs can only have [inline elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.3) as children.

As soon as the parser encounters a `<div>`, it auto-closes the `<p>`.

Compare

```
<p id="g">
  <span>kk</span>
  <div>ee</div>
  <div>jff</div>
</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var ii = document.getElementById("g");
  var hh = ii.getElementsByTagName('span');
  alert(hh.length);
</script>​
```

Comment: Thank you.  The first comment to your answer after 8 years.